# Getting syntax error when inserting one dimensional array to jsonb column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns conversation_id which is a text field and then participants which is a jsonb column. I am trying to insert one dimensional values to the jsonb column using the insert statement like below -

```
INSERT INTO public.conversations(conversation_id, participants) 
VALUES ('123456', '{"14160000000","17780000000"}');
```

I get an error

> Syntax error at or near "{"

Create table script:

```
create table conversations 
(
    id uuid not null,
    conversation_id text UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY not null,
    participants jsonb not null,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    avatar_url varchar(500),
    last_message varchar(32000)
)
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. Could you show the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Hello @LaurenzAlbe Added the create table command. All I am looking to add is a set of phone numbers to the jsonb column

Comment: A JSON array uses brackets (`[]`), not braces (`{}`).

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, can you put it as an answer. Also could you also help with select statement to query for a specific phone number in that jsonb column?

Comment: Start a new question about the query. But this time spend some time on research before you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON array is syntactically wrong, it should use brackets:

```json
'["14160000000","17780000000"]'
```